# VMWare host unable to access guest OS by name

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, oracle

After an automated installation of Ubuntu on a VMWare Workstation, I don't have any DNS issues whatsoever. However, after installing Oracle Linux 7.4, I can ping the guest by IP from the host, but not by it's name. Is there a built-in DNS with which I must register the VM? If that's so, how?

Comment: The problem is that you start off your question with saying "[you] don't have any DNS issues whatsoever." Yet, you do have DNS issues, because you can't access the Linux system by hostname. But, you didn't post any information about your network or anything to go on to direct you. The simplest and most direct answer is this: Whatever DNS server your HOST system queries needs an A record in it for that Linux server.

Comment: I believe you have missed the point, that I don't have any issues with Ubuntu, but I do with Oracle Linux. Watching any Ubuntu install on VMWare makes me think that the automated installer does apply some changes either in the guest OS or some internal VMWare Workstation configuration, to make the host accessible by name. I am just wondering what they are, if somebody knows it, or where to look?